# How can I request a web storage quota increase now that things are deprecated?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, indexeddb, persistent-storage, quota

I'm having an issue where my app isn't getting access to enough storage, and I don't know how to request more storage. It looks like one used to be able to do something like:

```
var requestedBytes = 1024*1024*10; // 10MB

navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(requestedBytes,
    grantedBytes => console.log('grantedBytes', grantedBytes),
    e => console.log('Error', e)
)
```

But that API is deprecated now (see [Google's Quota Management API page](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/11/Quota-Management-API-Fast-Facts) for instance)

Is this even possible anymore? The only thing I've found is `navigator.storage.persist()`, but that's useless if I'm getting a tiny quota.

*(Aside: I'm particularly having issues because in testing I used a HUGE amount of storage due to a bug and then it throttled my further quota even tinier (like 100kB) and so it would also be nice to even know how to reset the quota manually as a user, let alone a developer.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no standard way of doing this.

In Chrome, an extension (installed by the user or admin) can grant an origin "unlimitedStorage", but... that's not the web. We (the Chrome team) are looking at expanding the storage available to origins by altering our heuristics; no API calls required. (The current heuristics lead to allowing each origin 6% of disk size, which is way too low for powerful web apps.)

Other browsers have other heuristics for how much storage they assign. There is some discussion about allowing sites to create multiple "buckets" of data with differing priorities (via new APIs), and thus allowing a site to have a "low priority" bucket that can store more data but which is more volatile and can be discarded by the browser under storage pressure. But these thoughts are extremely early.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, seems like it would make sense to allow apps to differentiate between "this is required for the app to run offline" and "this is high-priority extra media" and "this is low-priority extra media".

Comment: Relatedly, it seems there should be a point where an app is considered... trusted? And then it gets to do things like display actual onbeforeunload messages like the olden days. Provided user trusts app, detailed onbeforeunload messages are WAY better than the generic "you may lose data". I see why they're banned on random pages, but if you spend hours/week on a site, obvi they should be able to tell you why they're blocking the tab-close.